# SQL query equality comparison with special character that is equal to everything

Tags: sql, oracle, comparator, equality

I am writing a python script that gets info from a database through SQL queries. Let's say we have an SQL array with information about some people. I have one query that can retrieve this information about a specific person whose name I pass as an argument to the query.

```
(" SELECT telephone FROM People_info WHERE name=%s " % (name))
```

Is it possible to pass as an argument a special character or something like that will return me the telephone for all the names? Meaning something that when I compare with every name the result will be equal? I want to use only one query for all the cases (either if I want the info about one person or all of them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LIKE` and the wild card `%` which matches no, one or any number of any characters.

```
SELECT telephone
       FROM people_info
       WHERE name LIKE '%';
```

However, it won't show records where `name IS NULL`.

Maybe the optimizer is smart enough to see, that this actually equivalent to a `WHERE name IS NOT NULL` and uses an index, if there is one. But maybe it don't see it, then this may come as higher price than necessary. So I'd rather change the `WHERE` clause (or completely omit it, if I wanted **all** records) in the application to what I actually want, then use such tricks.

Answer (score 2):

You can edit the SQL code in

```
SELECT telephone FROM People_info WHERE name=nvl(%s, name)
```

and pass `null` if you want to get all the records

Notice that this will never get the records where `name is null`, but I suppose this is not a problem.

Comment: If the parameter I am passing to the query from python is name_param (e.g. name_param='Alex') how can I pass null? I tried name_param = None but is not working.